# Adding additional weapons to rock-paper-scissors

Tags: rock-paper-scissors

Many of us are probably aware of the classic 'Rock-paper-scissors' game. I'm looking for an expansion with as many weapons as possible.

One popular alternative is '[Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock](http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html)'. Is there any longer expansion available?

Answer (score 16):

Well, I think your need is probably satisfied by [RPS-101: 101 gesture Rock-Paper-Scissors](http://www.umop.com/rps101.htm). There are apparently 5,050 possible outcomes to this game, which should keep you entertained for a while...

For something slightly less mindblowingly hardcore, the same author has also developed [7, 9, 11, 15 and 25 gesture variants](http://www.umop.com/rps.htm). These get complicated quickly! As an example, the 15 gesture version looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I was going to make up "gun" and "marijuana" because these American Sign Language hand signals are commonly known, and they look different than RPS lizard, and Spock. I working with the relationships between the objects, but since there were 90 ways to graph it it might have taken a while to get the right solution. Glad to see someone already did.

Comment: It's worth noting that the 101 gesture version includes a number of two-handed gestures whereas all the other versions by this author are exclusively one-handed gestures.

Answer (score -2):

To see what beats what in any version draw out just the circle and whatever gets beat by something go 1/2 of the total if the amount is even and 1 more than half if it's odd.

Comment: I don't quite follow this. Are you saying you need to assign a number to each option, and then do some math to that number? Could you add an example, and flesh out your answer a bit so it stands on its own rather than referencing other answers? (Also: welcome to Board & Card Games!)